# why won't this validate (jquery problem)?

Tags: jquery, validation, xhtml-1.0-strict, xhtml

On my site I'm using the jquery cycle plugin for a slideshow with a pager. 
This example:
http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/pager.html

So in the head of my document, I have a script similar to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#s4').before('<div id="nav">').cycle({ 
    fx:     'turnDown', 
    speed:  'fast', 
    timeout: 3000, 
    pager:  '#nav' 
});
</script>
```

My doc type is XHTML Strict.

When I try and validate the page, I get the following errors:
"document type does not allow element "div" here"
and
"end tag for "div" omitted, but OMITTAG NO was specified" because the div tag isn't closed.

Is there a way to use the jquery and get it to validate?

Comment: Can you link to your HTML or post a sample of your HTML?

Comment: Nevermind, I got the same problem on Mikes example page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, the reason your code is not validating is because certain characters are not allowed in `XHTML` (e.g. "`<`", etc.) so they must be wrapped in `CDATA` sections in `XHTML` (due to the strict nature of `XML` parsing rules). `HTML` comment markers (specfically, the double dashes "`--`") are also not allowed and shouldn't appear in a `SCRIPT` block since they're not <del>valid</del> understandable JavaScript. So instead of using `HTML` comment markers, you should wrap your code inside a "CDATA marked section" to pass the validator and not confuse the JavaScript engines:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$('#s4').before('<div id="nav">').cycle({ 
    fx:     'turnDown', 
    speed:  'fast', 
    timeout: 3000, 
    pager:  '#nav' 
});
//]]>
</script>
```

Take a look at the following pages for more information:

1. [XHTML 1.0 recommendation: 4.8. Script and Style elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.8)
2. [Properly Using CSS and JavaScript in XHTML Documents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/properly_using_css_and_javascript_in_xhtml_documents)

Comment: Thanks, very useful to know. Much better than trying to get round the validator in roundabout ways.

Answer (score 8):

If you put HTML comment tags into your script block the validator will ignore that block of code and validate correctly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
$('#s4').before('<div id="nav">').cycle({ 
    fx:     'turnDown', 
    speed:  'fast', 
    timeout: 3000, 
    pager:  '#nav' 
});
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: the validator didn't seem to respect the pseudo-HTML comment; using `<div><\/div>` (eg escaping the slash) worked instead

Answer (score 1):

You could probably get rid of the errors by doing:

```
$('#s4').before('<' + 'div id="nav">').cycle({ ...
```

This should keep the validator from detecting any HTML inside your script tag.  Me - I'd live with the error, knowing it was a problem with the validator not my code.